# Getting data from one array in another

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to rewrite a script to improve it's perfomance. Currently, it is a switch statement with multiple embedded ifs. The switch checks the value of `$type` and the ifs check the value of `$unit`, then inside the ifs, the line to be echoed is constructed from the `$message` array.

For example:

```
switch($type){
    case 1234:
        if($unit == "a"){
            echo "<td>$message[2]</td>
            <td>$message[5]</td>
            ...";
        }elseif($unit == "b"){
            ...
        }
    ...
```

The `$message` array contains all the information needed, but is in a different order depending on `$type` and `$unit`, so this check sorts out the order.

This makes for a slow page load, especially when 500+ messages are loaded.

My attempt to optimize this was to create a multidimensional array with all of the message order pre-formatted and then access it via something like:

```
echo $format[$type][$unit];
```

But since the data that I would need for that is in the `$message` array I don't know how to use that data. If I put the `$format` declaration in the same loop that generates the `$message` arrays that could work by just calling `$message[2]` etc. but I feel like that would hurt performance.

How could I dynamically call the data inside the formatting?

**Edit**

To clarify,

The `$message` array is created by exploding a comma delimited string that is retrieved from the database (I did not create the database, I would love to fix the way this is done but I cannot).

`$message` will look something like this:

```
$message[2] //TimeStamp1
$message[3] //TimeStamp2
$message[4] //Could be a 1/0 for true/false, could be a float to resemble a necessary value
```

So run on this assumption: For `$type` 1234, `$message[4]` should be retrieved as the 1/0 for true/false, but for for `$type` 5678 `$message[4]` should be retrieved as the float so:

```
if($type == 1234){
    if($unit = "a"){
        echo "<td>$message[2]</td>
        <td>$message[3]</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>$message[4]</td>";
    }elseif($unit = "b"){
        echo "<td>$message[2]</td>
        <td>$message[3]</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>$message[4]</td>
        <td></td>";
    }
}elseif($type = 5678){
    if($unit = "a"){
        echo "<td>$message[2]</td>
        <td>$message[3]</td>
        <td>$message[4]</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>";
    }elseif($unit = "b"){
        echo "<td>$message[2]</td>
        <td>$message[3]</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>$message[4]</td>";
    }
}
```

Where `$message[4]` (and other values) is placed is dependent on the `$type` and the `$unit` values.

Comment: How is the array created? From the database, a file? Looping over 500 elements in an array *should not* be a bottleneck in of itself.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I added an edit to my question explaining it's origin.

Comment: 500+ items not much at all... Give us a real (short) example of your source string and give us example of what you want to have

Comment: @Konstantin I gave an example of what we've got and how it outputs, although I changed the switches for ifs for the sake of this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a multi-dimensional array simply make an array of objects such that you have key/value pairs such as "a": messageA, "b": messageB, "c":messageC, etc. where that one object w/ keys "a", "b", and "c" are in one index. That way you only have to loop through so many indices.